# Test for a trigger on ServiceReport object

Tags: trigger, unit-test, fieldservice

I had to make a trigger for ServiceReport, my requirement was "do not allow the report to be generated if the worksteps are not complete". Only way I could think of was trigger before insert.

But it turns out this trigger can not be tested as the object ServiceReport can't be created in a test class because it is created through an api call. And when I try standard dml, apparently, ServiceReport is not even an SObject??!

`ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport();`

`insert sr;`

gives the following error: **DML requires SObject or SObject list type: ServiceReport**

So my problem is I can't deploy the code because of 0% coverage.

I thought of getting the trigger to run in an update instead of an insert and get the minimium coverage, using @seeAllData to get an existing ServiceReport and update it. But also no assignment is allowed. See the following query

`ServiceReport sr = [select Id, ParentId, DocumentName, IsSigned, Status  from ServiceReport LIMIT 1][0];`

throws the following error: **Illegal assignment from ServiceReport to ServiceReport**

If someone had this problem, or can give me any ideas, help would be most appreciated.

PS: I already tried putting all code in a method and straight invoking it from the test class, but it doesn't work either. It is a trigger, not a class, can't invoke its methods.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the user running the test class has the required Field Service license/permissions? Given this is a feature license if the running user doesn't have access it can cause issues like this. Also I'm sure you've checked, but is Field Service enabled in the development org that you're doing this work in?